# How to plot bode diagram of a signal using fft in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fft

I want to plot bode diagram of the following system both using `bode` and `fft`:

```
%// System info
num=[0 1];   %// Numerator of z-transform of impulse response of system
den=[1 -0.8]; %// Denominator of z-transform of impulse response of system
```

I used `dbode` to plot bode method:

```
figure(6); dbode(num,den,1) %// 1 is sampling time Ts
```

As I want to do it from `fft` method, it gets wrong:

```
Ts=1;
Fs=1/Ts;
L=length(ym);
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); %// Next power of 2 from length of ym
H2=fft(ym,NFFT)./fft(u,NFFT); 
f=Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
ww=f*2*pi;

figure(7)
semilogx(20*log10(abs(H2(1:NFFT/2+1))))

figure(10)
semilogx((180/pi)*angle(H2(1:NFFT/2+1)))
```

Bode diagram using `bode`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea

[Here is my data (u and ym)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdxl1vrgjzzlndk/test.mat?dl=0)

Comment: Data is missing: "The file you're looking for has been moved or deleted." Also, generally, getting the transfer function by taking the FFT of the output divided by the FFT of the input is a pretty poor technique, and very prone to noise. `tfestimate` is probably a better way to go about it.

Comment: If you give us links to the pictures, we can post them for you.

Comment: Thanks
1.[bode](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zqd10uvxb26xavg/bode.jpg?dl=0)
2.[fft_mag](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o88b3lydq18drre/fft_angle.jpg?dl=0)
3.[fft_angle](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3wcid3mdohy0fed/fft_mag.jpg?dl=0)

By the way, I found it with `spa` and `iddata` that's perfect, but I wonder why this is so different comparing to two other(from system and `spa`/`iddata`) methods?

Comment: Can you correct the (bad) link to the data?

Comment: BTW, `dbode` doesn't exist in MATLAB.

Comment: Sorry. I corrected the (bad) link.

Comment: I don't know why but `dbode` exist in mine. It's sth like bode, but in discrete time format.

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/search.html?qdoc=dbode&submitsearch=Search

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your data and compared it with the theoretical transfer function in the time-domain and it isn't a bad fit **if you ignore some of the data**:

```
t = 1:length(u);
num=[0 1];   %// Numerator of z-transform of impulse response of system
den=[1 -0.8]; %// Denominator of z-transform of impulse response of system
H = tf(num,den,1)
[yy,tt,xx] = step(H,max(t));
plot(t-10,ym-2.2,tt,yy)
```

You'll notice that I have discarded the time values before 10 and shifted the response values down by about 2.2. This gives the following plot (in Octave):

[image]

I suggest you do the same thing when taking the FFT:

```
L = length(ym(t>=10));
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L);
H2 = fft(ym(t>=10)-2.2,NFFT)./fft(u(t>=10),NFFT);
f=Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);ww=f*2*pi;
[mag,ph,w ] = bode(H);
semilogx(ww,20*log10(abs(H2(1:NFFT/2+1))),w,20*log10(abs(mag)))
```

[image]

The DC level of the transfer function is correct, but the poor FFT technique yields too much noise at (relatively) higher frequencies. [`tfestimate`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tfestimate.html) would be a better choice to estimate the transfer based on the measurement data (again remember to pre-process the data the same way as I have just done here). It is part of the Signal Processing Toolbox.